# tabular: caption and align problem

Tags: tables, captions

What I would like to create are two tables side by side, each with its own caption above the table. This is my attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,systeme}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{| *{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} |}}
\hline
$\theta $ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \hline\hline
20 & 22.727 & 22.272 & 1.0204 \\ \hline
25 & 17.962 & 17.670 & 1.0165 \\ \hline
30 & 14.416 & 14.234 & 1.0127 \\ \hline
35 & 11.631 & 11.528 & 1.0090 \\ \hline
40 & 9.8771 & 9.8264 & 1.0052 \\ \hline
45 & 9.1780 & 9.1658 & 1.0013 \\ \hline
50 & error & error & error \\ \hline
\caption{$x_1 = 0.4$}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\quad
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{| *{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} |}}
\hline
$\theta $ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \hline\hline
20 & 39.976 & 37.827 & 1.0568 \\ \hline
25 & 30.827 & 29.273 & 1.0531 \\ \hline
30 & 24.157 & 23.027 & 1.0491 \\ \hline
35 & 19.205 & 18.373 & 1.0453 \\ \hline
40 & 15.486 & 14.867 & 1.0417 \\ \hline
45 & 12.577 & 12.115 & 1.0381 \\ \hline
50 & error & error & error \\ \hline
\caption{$x_1 = 0.5$}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the caption is an unusual position, and the tables are not positioned next to each other

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Unless you change the margins or the widths of the table cells, your tables won't fit next to each other.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but why did you put the `\caption` command inside the `tabular` environment?

Answer (score 6):

Here are two possibilities:

I have moved the `\caption` command from inside the `tabular` environment to right before `\begin{tabular}` so there is no need to use `\restylefloat`. I have also drastically reduced the margins in order to make the two tables fit into the textwidth. Lastly, I have also changed the column specifiers from `7` to `4` as you only need four columns in your tables. In order to position the tables next to each other, put them in the same `table` environment and each of the `tabulars` inside of an own `minipage` environment.

Since you used the option `[H]` to place the table exactly where is was defined in the code, I have added the second example. In this I have completely removed the `table` environment and used `\captionof{table}` from  the `caption` package instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,systeme}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{float}
%\floatstyle{plaintop}
%\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\caption{$x_1 = 0.4$}
\begin{tabular}{| *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} |}}
\hline
$\theta $ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \hline\hline
20 & 22.727 & 22.272 & 1.0204 \\ \hline
25 & 17.962 & 17.670 & 1.0165 \\ \hline
30 & 14.416 & 14.234 & 1.0127 \\ \hline
35 & 11.631 & 11.528 & 1.0090 \\ \hline
40 & 9.8771 & 9.8264 & 1.0052 \\ \hline
45 & 9.1780 & 9.1658 & 1.0013 \\ \hline
50 & error & error & error \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\caption{$x_1 = 0.5$}
\begin{tabular}{| *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} |}}
\hline
$\theta $ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \hline\hline
20 & 39.976 & 37.827 & 1.0568 \\ \hline
25 & 30.827 & 29.273 & 1.0531 \\ \hline
30 & 24.157 & 23.027 & 1.0491 \\ \hline
35 & 19.205 & 18.373 & 1.0453 \\ \hline
40 & 15.486 & 14.867 & 1.0417 \\ \hline
45 & 12.577 & 12.115 & 1.0381 \\ \hline
50 & error & error & error \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}


\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\captionof{table}{$x_1 = 0.4$}
\begin{tabular}{| *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} |}}
\hline
$\theta $ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \hline\hline
20 & 22.727 & 22.272 & 1.0204 \\ \hline
25 & 17.962 & 17.670 & 1.0165 \\ \hline
30 & 14.416 & 14.234 & 1.0127 \\ \hline
35 & 11.631 & 11.528 & 1.0090 \\ \hline
40 & 9.8771 & 9.8264 & 1.0052 \\ \hline
45 & 9.1780 & 9.1658 & 1.0013 \\ \hline
50 & error & error & error \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\captionof{table}{$x_1 = 0.5$}
\begin{tabular}{| *{4}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm} |}}
\hline
$\theta $ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \hline\hline
20 & 39.976 & 37.827 & 1.0568 \\ \hline
25 & 30.827 & 29.273 & 1.0531 \\ \hline
30 & 24.157 & 23.027 & 1.0491 \\ \hline
35 & 19.205 & 18.373 & 1.0453 \\ \hline
40 & 15.486 & 14.867 & 1.0417 \\ \hline
45 & 12.577 & 12.115 & 1.0381 \\ \hline
50 & error & error & error \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

---

If you don't want to decrease the margins, you might want to consider decreasing the column width. You could for example use `c` tpe columns. With this column type, both tables will easily fit next to each other in the standard text width of  the `article` documentclass. Personally, I'd prefer tables with less lines, so in the following MWE, I have als included an example on how to achieve that, using the `booktabs` package. (If you'd also like to align the numbers with respect to the decimal separator, you might want to have a look into the `siunitx` or the `dcolumn` package.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,systeme}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\caption{$x_1 = 0.4$}
\begin{tabular}{| *{4}{c|}}
\hline
$\theta $ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \hline\hline
20 & 22.727 & 22.272 & 1.0204 \\ \hline
25 & 17.962 & 17.670 & 1.0165 \\ \hline
30 & 14.416 & 14.234 & 1.0127 \\ \hline
35 & 11.631 & 11.528 & 1.0090 \\ \hline
40 & 9.8771 & 9.8264 & 1.0052 \\ \hline
45 & 9.1780 & 9.1658 & 1.0013 \\ \hline
50 & error & error & error \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\caption{$x_1 = 0.5$}
\begin{tabular}{| *{4}{c|}}
\hline
$\theta $ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \hline\hline
20 & 39.976 & 37.827 & 1.0568 \\ \hline
25 & 30.827 & 29.273 & 1.0531 \\ \hline
30 & 24.157 & 23.027 & 1.0491 \\ \hline
35 & 19.205 & 18.373 & 1.0453 \\ \hline
40 & 15.486 & 14.867 & 1.0417 \\ \hline
45 & 12.577 & 12.115 & 1.0381 \\ \hline
50 & error & error & error \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{$x_1 = 0.4$}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
$\theta $ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \midrule
20 & 22.727 & 22.272 & 1.0204 \\ 
25 & 17.962 & 17.670 & 1.0165 \\ 
30 & 14.416 & 14.234 & 1.0127 \\ 
35 & 11.631 & 11.528 & 1.0090 \\ 
40 & 9.8771 & 9.8264 & 1.0052 \\ 
45 & 9.1780 & 9.1658 & 1.0013 \\ 
50 & error & error & error \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\caption{$x_1 = 0.5$}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
$\theta $ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \midrule
20 & 39.976 & 37.827 & 1.0568 \\ 
25 & 30.827 & 29.273 & 1.0531 \\ 
30 & 24.157 & 23.027 & 1.0491 \\ 
35 & 19.205 & 18.373 & 1.0453 \\ 
40 & 15.486 & 14.867 & 1.0417 \\ 
45 & 12.577 & 12.115 & 1.0381 \\ 
50 & error & error & error \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As your two tables seem to be closely related, you could also combine them into one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{The caption text}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$x_1 = 0.4$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$x_1 = 0.5$} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
$\theta $ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ & $\eta$ & $\nu$ & $\rho$ \\ \midrule
20 & 22.727 & 22.272 & 1.0204 & 39.976 & 37.827 & 1.0568\\ 
25 & 17.962 & 17.670 & 1.0165 & 30.827 & 29.273 & 1.0531\\ 
30 & 14.416 & 14.234 & 1.0127 & 24.157 & 23.027 & 1.0491\\ 
35 & 11.631 & 11.528 & 1.0090 & 19.205 & 18.373 & 1.0453\\ 
40 & 9.8771 & 9.8264 & 1.0052 & 15.486 & 14.867 & 1.0417\\ 
45 & 9.1780 & 9.1658 & 1.0013 & 12.577 & 12.115 & 1.0381\\ 
50 & error  & error  & error  & error  & error  & error \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

A layout with `siunitx` and the `floatrow` package (incompatible with `float`, but redefines macros from `float`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,systeme}
\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\begin{table}[H]
\floatsetup[table]{floatrowsep=qquad}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\sisetup{table-format =2.4, table-number-alignment=center}
\begin{floatrow}
\centering
\makegapedcells
\ttabbox{\caption{$x_1 = 0.4$}\label{x1: 4}}{
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{1cm}|*{3}{S |}}
\hline
{$\theta $} & {$\eta$} & {$\nu$} & {$\rho$} \\ \hline\hline
20 & 22.727 & 22.272 & 1.0204 \\ \hline
25 & 17.962 & 17.670 & 1.0165 \\ \hline
30 & 14.416 & 14.234 & 1.0127 \\ \hline
35 & 11.631 & 11.528 & 1.0090 \\ \hline
40 & 9.8771 & 9.8264 & 1.0052 \\ \hline
45 & 9.1780 & 9.1658 & 1.0013 \\ \hline
50 & {error} & {error} & {error} \\ \hline

\end{tabular}}
\ttabbox{\caption{$x_1 = 0.5$}\label{x1: 5}}
{\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}p{1cm}|*{3}{S |}}
\hline
{$\theta $} & {$\eta$} & {$\nu$} & {$\rho$} \\ \hline\hline
20 & 39.976 & 37.827 & 1.0568 \\ \hline
25 & 30.827 & 29.273 & 1.0531 \\ \hline
30 & 24.157 & 23.027 & 1.0491 \\ \hline
35 & 19.205 & 18.373 & 1.0453 \\ \hline
40 & 15.486 & 14.867 & 1.0417 \\ \hline
45 & 12.577 & 12.115 & 1.0381 \\ \hline
50 & {error} & {error} & {error} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]